# Why are there so many new users with 101 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

Nearly half of the 
[35 newest users in Ubuntu StackExchange](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=newest) have exactly 101 reputation and no history of participation on the site. What's the explanation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You start with 1 point. You get 100 points for associating your account with one on another Stack-site (provided that other account has 200+ rep). There's more of an explanation [here on the StackOverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/).

Comment: So if I've already associated my other accounts, and _then_ I exceed 200 rep, will my other accounts get the +100 then?

Comment: Don't think so. It's a at-registration bonus AFAIK.

Comment: @Jeremy (and later readers): Unassociate and re-associate your accounts to get the bonus (after one of them has 200 rep) in that case.

Comment: The association bonus is applied whenever you associate with another SE account with sufficient rep.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus