# Markdown isn't parsed after a question rollback.

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

I just rolled back [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/285/why-are-there-so-many-new-users-with-101-reputation) and now the Markdown hyperlink appears unprocessed:

[image: screenshot]

When I click Edit, the preview displays correctly, so I know there isn't a syntax mistake:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported on the [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63390/rolling-back-question-edits-occasionally-kills-formatting) already - I'm sure they're looking into this.